# authlogic current_user is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have the standard current_user methods in my application_controller.

```
   def current_user_session
        return @current_user_session if defined?
(@current_user_session)
        @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
        return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        @current_user = current_user_session &&
current_user_session.record
    end
```

In my UserSessionController create method, I checked for
registration_complete? (simply a check on a value of a column, which
works fine) and then redirect the user to the user edit page if the
registration is not complete. When I debug this, I can see that the
attempted_record for the @user_session object exists and it's pointing
to the correct user, but the current_user method in
the                     redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user),
always returns nil.

What's going wrong here?

```
def create
        @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
        # uses a block to prevent double render error...
        # because oauth and openid use redirects
        @user_session.save do |result|
            if result
                flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
                if @user_session.new_registration?
                    logger.info "Session controller : new
registration"
                    logger.info "Complete -
#{@user_session.registration_complete?}"
                    flash[:notice] = "Please review profile"
                    redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
                else
                    if @user_session.registration_complete?
                        logger.info "Session Controller - registration
complete"
                    else
                        flash[:notice] = "Please complete profile"
                        logger.info "Session Controller - registration
not complete"
                        redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
#current_user nil here
                    end
                end
                redirect_to current_user ? profile_url(current_user) :
login_url
            else
                if @user_session.errors.on(:user)
                    # if we set error on the base object, likely it's
because we didn't find a user
                    render :action => :confirm
                else
                    render :action => :new
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: If you still want the answer to this questions... please see the answer to question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5305306/1188763 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this and used that very same authentication system on one of my applications. You don't mention it and that's why I'm proposing this to you if you do have then I'd need to see more of your application_controller, so anyway try and add this before the methods.

```
helper_method :current_user
```

I just had a duh moment, try doing this instead of passing a block to the save method.

```
if @user_session.save
  # rest of your logic here
end
```

"if result" might not do what you expect it to do.

Else inspect this @user_session.record instead of current_user, if it's still nul your problem is not current_user.

I need to get home, I'll check back later tonight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my appcontroller. I already have that helper method.

http://pastie.org/1113118

Comment: Ok, looks alright to me, can you tell me if current_user under the @user_session.new_registration? validation is non nul ? I'm trying to find fault with anything and I can't, I'm thinking @user_session.registration_complete? might change what's inside @user_session. Otherwise store current_user inside another variable such as @user then use that in your redirect to see if it works.

Comment: Actually is current_user working anywhere in that create method ?

Comment: actually, no it isnt.
I have updated the pastie with the session.rb file of authlogic-connect, which is the gem I am using for aeuthetication. It contains the registration complete method.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. authlogic-connect requires passing a block for oauth authentication, since it's a two step process.

Comment: Well I picked up the example at http://github.com/viatropos/authlogic-connect-example.git and thought it would be easy to get up and running with openid at least (as I have yet to do anything with oauth). If you started from that example I think there are some serious issues with it, one being that there is no such thing as params[:user_session] passed from the form. I leave with this, if you only need openid authentication with authlogic check out this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic. Sorry and goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with authlogic and rails 3, and the problem that i figured out was
the apache http authentication that was enabled in my production server,
here is the solution to get that fixed, check [Rails + Authlogic @current_user problem - "Show" method no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764002/rails-authlogic-current-user-problem-show-method-no-longer-works/7544316#7544316)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this to rails2:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details

  #Authlogic
  filter_parameter_logging :password

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
end
```

and this to rails3:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
end
```

**/config/application.rb**

```
# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.  
config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```