# Rails + Authlogic @current_user problem - "Show" method no longer works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I implemented Authlogic in my rails app which works and tests great. Users can login, logout, etc.

However, since I changed my methods in the **users_controller** to use the **@current_user** variable, none of my user methods or forms (other than "index" strangely...) work!

For example, this "Show" methods works and shows the user profile for any user (Note: I want to eventually restrict this to the currently logged in user somehow):

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

If I follow the show method as shown in the Authlogic rails cast and the official example to:

```
def show
    @user = @current_user
end
```

I get all kinds of `undefined method METHOD for nil:NilClass` errors. It seems as the though the **@current_user** variable doesn't contain any of the user's information.

I assume the @current_user is pulling info from the **current_user** method as defined in the application controller below:

```
def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
```

What am I missing? My hunch is that there is no mapping between the User object from the user model and the current_user method. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

~Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't it be just

```
def show
    @user = current_user
end
```

without the `@`?

Comment: Correct, Devise provides the `current_user` method for you.

Comment: It makes sense to me know that I'm invoking a method rather than a predefined variable. It was a little confusing since much of the example code online has it set to @user = @current_user. Thanks again for your help! This is why I love StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

current_user is a helper that comes with authlogic, so you have to use it without '@'.
Usually you create @sothing to pass it from controller to view, so you will access something you prepared in the action method.

Comment: That makes sense...I wonder why they had it set that way in the example code on Github?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with authlogic and rails 3, it was because of the apache http authentication that i had on my production server.
And i got that fixed by adding the below line to my user_session.rb(model)

```
    allow_http_basic_auth false
```

this is the blog link that saved my life *phew* http://www.christopherirish.com/2011/08/12/rails-3-authlogic-sessions-not-persisting-in-production/comment-page-1/#comment-181

Comment: what is actullay the problem is ? can you clarify ?  what does `allow_http_basic_auth false' do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def
if @current_user
 @user = @current_user
else
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Just a guess, give a try on it.

Comment: This wasn't the full answer, but I ended up using this idea to let non-logged in users see profiles. Thanks!